# JavaScript - Update innerHTML using setInterval not visible some times in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I was try to update a Label innerHTML using JavaScript by setInterval which is not displaying some times. But After clicking other area of `<body>` it displaying after call the function.

> Everything looks good on FF and issue on Google Chrome.

```js
var LABEL_COUNTDOWN = "Your code will expire in ，$TIMER$ seconds";
function initCodeTimer() {
    var timeleft = 10;
    document.querySelector('.jq-message--label').innerHTML = "";
    SEND_CODE_COUNTDOWN_TIMER = setInterval(function () {
        document.querySelector('.jq-message--label').innerHTML = LABEL_COUNTDOWN.split("$TIMER$").join(timeleft);
        timeleft -= 1;
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(SEND_CODE_COUNTDOWN_TIMER);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.jq-message--label{
    display: block;
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="initCodeTimer();">START</button>
<label class="jq-message--label"></label>
```

I had inspect the label element and found innerHTML content is rendering but not displaying on page. Was not sure what is the root cause.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks - DS

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Just onclick event of a button.

Comment: By "not displaying" you mean vanished from the page, or not displaying the right up-to-date content?

Comment: I was inspect the element and found innerHTML content is rendering but not displaying on page. I can't upload screen short here.

Comment: Can you include a snippet?

Comment: Think the pb lies in other part of code not shown in description. A jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: Guess one, `document.querySelector('.jq-message--label')` ends up selecting other element with same classname. Guess two, css problem, inpsect the computed style of that element.

Comment: I turned the code into a snippet to demonstrate it works fine, so the problem must be elsewhere. If you can't reproduce here, it will be hard for us to help you. If it happens on a specific browser/environment, please add the precision to the post.

Comment: @Kaddath You are correct! This only happening on Chrome. FF Looks good.

Comment: @hackape nope its unique in DOM (.jq-message--label).

Comment: If chrome only it might as well be an extension that interferes. Just a thought. Run into that time to time, try to reproduce in incognito mode. If cannot reproduce, then 99% it's an extension.

Comment: Just as a side comment, If you push the button many times, the counter will not stop in negative amounts.

Comment: sometimes? hmmm, then probably it wasn't a AJAX success though AJAX complete. try verifying if it was success or not.

Comment: Nope -  its called only inside ajax success.